# event not defined in firefox but working on chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function :-

`$scope.getBillDetails=function($event){
    bill_id=event.target.id`

And I call it in the following way on ng-click:-

`<td><button type="button" id="{{user.bill_id}}" href="#mySlider2" data-slide="next" class="btn btn-primary right" ng-click="getBillDetails($event)">View Details</button></td>`

My code is working fine on Chrome but it fails in firefox saying event not defined. Can someone please help me out. I saw some other posts regarding the same issue but did not get any proper solution.

Comment: `event` is a microsoft internet exploder non standard global event object, that chrome in their wisdom has decided to implement ... usually, the first argument to an event handler is an event object that you can use instead (even on chrome and more recent versions of IE - so there's never any reason to use the non-standard global event object, never)

Comment: So how should I change the above declaration??

Comment: sorry, no idea, angularjs seems to make things less obvious

Answer (score 0):

Use the argument you named as `$event`

Change

```
$scope.getBillDetails=function($event){
    bill_id=event.target.id
```

To

```
$scope.getBillDetails=function($event){
    bill_id=$event.target.id
           // ^^ matches function argument
```